# Вертикальный слайдер

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте, есть слайдер, с вертикальным возможностью вызова [http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#demo](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo)  , но мне понадобилось вывести его вертикально и по 4 - шт на строчку, Jquery знаю поверхностно, помогите с решением теоретично, либо буду рад увидеть альтернативные решения.

Answer (score 2):

Вот неплохой вертикальный слайдер [***jQuery.silver_track***](http://tulios.github.io/jquery.silver_track/)

Если не подходит поищи в гугле или яндексе по запросу: ***Vertical slider*** , там готовых слайдеров сотни.

Answer (score 1):

Там в меню демо-страницы есть пункт Vertical, в которой написано, что вы должны прописать в параметрах вашей карусели

```
$(".vertical .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
btnNext: ".vertical .next",
btnPrev: ".vertical .prev",
vertical: true
```

});

И с вашем списке в пункт меню `li` кладите не одну картинку, а сразу несколько, сколько вам надо.

Comment: Как вариант да, но не самое лучшее решение

Answer (score 0):

[Slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)
лучший слайдер на мой взгляд. На странице есть примеры почти на все случаи жизни, правда среди них нет вертикального слайдера, но в перечне параметров есть и эта опция: vertical: true